# javascript aggregation not working, just print side by side

Tags: javascript

```
let line1 = parseInt(prompt('Enter line1', 'number goes here'))   
let line2 = parseInt(prompt('Enter line2', 'number goes here'))   
let line3 = parseInt(prompt('Enter line3', 'number goes here'))  
console.log(`Environment of triangele is `+line1+line2+line3)
```

**strong text**
I want to print the result to the screen, but the path is written side by side.Where am i doing wrong??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2bbY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use concatenation to try to add numbers within a template string - everything will be coerced to a string. Perform the calculation of the numbers within one expression instead.

Always add [the `radix` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters) to your `parseInt` statements.

```js
const line1 = parseInt(prompt('Enter line1', 'number goes here'), 10);
const line2 = parseInt(prompt('Enter line2', 'number goes here'), 10);
const line3 = parseInt(prompt('Enter line3', 'number goes here'), 10);

console.log(`Environment of triangele is ${line1 + line2 + line3}`);
```

Comment: thank u so much but ı've got question. why did you add the ten at end of sentence?

Comment: That's the radix which I linked to in the answer. Generally it will default to 10 but not every time which is why it's a good idea to always include it.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(`Environment of triangele is `+line1+line2+line3)
```

is evaluated like this:

```
console.log(((`Environment of triangele is `+line1)+line2)+line3)
```

which results in + being interpreted as string concatenation.

You want:

```
console.log(`Environment of triangele is `+(line1+line2+line3))
```

or

```
console.log(`Environment of triangele is ${line1 + line2 + line3}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put something in quotes and then want to add, the rest of the numbers will be treated as strings and concatenated.
you can try this

```
let line = line1 + line2 + line3;
console.log(`Environment of triangele is `+line)
```

or This

```
console.log(`Environment of triangele is ${line1 + line2 + line3}`);
```